# Linear regression model and table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Geniuses!

So I am trying to do a linear regression model where it should take the inputs in a table if the input is labelled as the same in the linear regression model.
I have made a short video here and attached my dataset. I am not a big table-guy myself so some help would be very much appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQb1.png)

I have attached an image of my data.
Basically It should do a linear regression model in the blue field on the Y-inputs margin and X-input price - however only if the subcategory-value in the table corresponds with the subcategory in the linear regression table eg. Facadestilladser in B164 it should only base the linear regression on subcategories that are characterized in the table in I,J,K as Subcategory = Facadestilladser.

Luca

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQb1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it show no attempted model & relies entirely on external documentation, likely to vanish at any time, leaving no question at all.

Comment: Kindly paste a screenshot of your input data and provide another screenshot of what your would like to get as an output. Be specific about what your problem is and what you have tried already/why you are stuck. This is in part also to help others with a similar problem to find your question, and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming your question is just about switching column inputs i.e. you have a formula `=FUNC(A2:A10)` and you are looking to switch that A column input to column B or C based on some header/text selector/drop down cell.

Lets say column D is your generic input and if D1=A1 then D should contain all values from A, or if D1=B1 then D should pull values from B etc. In D2 to D10 put

```
=HLOOKUP($D$1, $A$1:$C$10, ROW()
```